# App not installing on developer iphone

Tags: sdk, coronasdk, installation

I just created a new app with corona sdk and tried to test it on my iphone. So I uploaded it through itunes and it appeared on my iphone. However I was not able to open the app, it was stuck on "installing...". Has this happened to anyone? Any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, if the IPA synchronizes in itunes, its seems it´s ok, however, try to reboot the device. There are a couple of issues installing apps in iOS 7.
Just in case, what I would do is :

- Verify you have created the application with the correct certificates as follows :

  - Code signing identity : your distribution profile
  - Provisioning profile : the one created for your app

Sometimes, if you generate an IPA with the incorrect development or distribution certificate it wont work. Sometimes, in the code signing identity we have our developer´s certificate and in provisioning profile we´ve got a different one than the distribution of the app one. Check them all and try it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created a new provisioning profile and uploaded my app through xcode and am now using it on my iphone. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Pleasure to help! and well done ;)